# Channel entries without URL field

Tags: channel-entries, url, ee5

Is it possible to have a channel where you do not have to define a URL name for every entry.
I want to have a channel for events which are only shown in a list (no extra page for each event) so it would be quite annoying to always come up with a unique id for the URL field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic creation of unique URL titles was a built-in feature of EE in v2. Apparently it was removed with v3. You can see some discussion of the issue on this bug report https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/21902/adding-a-new-entry-with-the-same-title-as-an-existing-one-does-not-auto-gen

Looks like there are **no plans to bring this functionality back** in later versions of EE. I'm surprised. It seemed like a smart feature and good for users.

That discussion does reference a **plugin** called **Smart URL Title** which can be used as a patch for this.
https://github.com/willowlight/Willow-Smart-URL-Title

> This addon will check for an existing URL Title in the same channel
>   and automatically append it to avoid errors when saving the entry.
>
> Example, if an existing URL title willow-smart-url-title exists, the
>   addon will change it to willow-smart-url-title-2. It will also
>   increment the number (up to 10) if future entries share the same URL
>   title.
>
> Additionally a message will be displayed under the URL Title field to
>   let the editor know that a duplicate URL was found, and the URL Title
>   was modified to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a title for a new entry, the URL title is auto-generated as you can plainly see. The URL title will always be required for every entry.

Just because each entry needs to have a unique URL title doesn't mean it needs to be used in anyway; it's just a unique identifier. Unfortunately it has to be unique and you won't be able to save a new entry until it is.

The only solution I could think of for this is creating a helper add-on to warn you before you try to save your entry that the URL title isn't unique, or automatically add an index counter to the end (so if you enter a title of "Test Entry", a URL title of "test-entry" is generated, but the add-on finds that title already exists, so it tries "test-entry-1", and if that exists, tries "test-entry-2", etc..).

It might be a fun side project to build, but I'm not sure it's worth it instead of just manually adding a "-1" (or "-2", "-3", etc..) to your URL titles if the title is already taken.

Comment: EE will enforce unique URLs. So even if you title every single entry the same, you'll still be good. Last time I checked it appends a number to the entry just as you described.

Comment: I checked an EE5 and an EE4 installation and tested; it doesn't automatically append a number anymore. It returns to the form and casts an error class and verbiage on the URL title field that it has to be unique. CraftCMS automatically does this though. I tested an EE2 installation and it does just append a number. Dunno why but they dropped that functionality, and I can't find a setting in EE4 or EE5 for this. Didn't check the docs for a config var though.

Comment: That's too bad. This used to be built into EE core in v2, as you said. I looked into this a bit more and added an answer here with more info.